# Cordova, issue after "cordova run android"

Tags: java, cordova, emulation

I just encountered this problem after creating an app with Cordova. I searched everywhere for this error but can't find anything in all google.

```
[BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 2.917 secs
Built the following apk(s):
        C:/MyApp/platforms/android/build/outputs/apk/android-debug.apk
ANDROID_HOME=C:\SDK
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\java\jdk1.8.0_152
No target specified and no devices found, deploying to emulator
Error: Cannot read property 'semver' of null][1]
```

What it mean? After this doesn't happen anything. Thanks in advance :)

[image: Console output]

Comment: Try to remove and re-add the android platform.

Comment: Run with `--verbose` and you should see the commands being executed immediately prior to the error. Let us know what those are.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you have created your AVD (Android Virtual Device) using API  27 as a system image. Try to delete it and create a new one, using either Oreo or Nougat system image.

As far as I understand it happens due to lack of corresponding mapping [here](https://github.com/apache/cordova-android/blob/697c8f129ce6bcc93d6c864e3bf80f195922ff84/bin/templates/cordova/lib/emulator.js#L190). If you will take a look at node_modules/android-versions/index.js you will see that API 26 is the latest supported one.

Answer (score 1):

This fixed it for me: [Cordova android emulation - Error: Cannot read property 'semver' of null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47018914/cordova-android-emulation-error-cannot-read-property-semver-of-null?rq=1)

```
find the path <project_root>/platforms/android/cordova/lib/emulator.js

find the line avd.target = 'Android ' + level.semver + ' (API level ' +    api_level + ')'; 

replace it with avd.target = 'Android ' + (level ? level.semver : '') + ' (API level ' + api_level + ')';
```

I'm using an emulated Android Nexus6 with API 24.