# Cordova android emulation - Error: Cannot read property 'semver' of null

Tags: cordova, emulation, device

Trying to emulate Android app with cordova, but get this error message:

Built the following apk(s):
    /Users/jnj/cordova/hello/platforms/android/build/outputs/apk/android-debug.apk
ANDROID_HOME=/Users/jnj/Library/Android/sdk
JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_151.jdk/Contents/Home

**Error: Cannot read property 'semver' of null**

Any solutions?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

This is due using an emulator with an unstable Developer Preview API version.

You probably have a device using API 27 (Android 8.1).

Open your AVD, remove that device and re-run.

It's also useful to use `--target <emulator_name>` when launching the emulator if you have more than one.

To get a list of available names to use, call the emulate command with `--list`

Comment: I got this error today, and fixed it by removing my 8.1 emulator and installing an 8.0 emulator.  Did the upstream fix not take yet?

Comment: That's right. Android Studio 3.1.2 uses an unstable, API 27 (Oreo) default emulator. Deleting this emulator and using a stable one (8.0 or lower API) solves the problem.

Comment: Note: I've found that `--list` only works with `run`, i.e., `cordova run --list`.

Answer (score 63):

The Mighty Chris is right, that is the problem and he fixed it upstream (thank you Chris!). However just to add to his answer, for people like me who cannot update cordova-android to include the patch, the fix is (for cordova-android v6.4.0):

- find the path `<project_root>/platforms/android/cordova/lib/emulator.js`
- find the line `avd.target = 'Android ' + level.semver + ' (API level ' + api_level + ')';`
- replace it with `avd.target = 'Android ' + (level ? level.semver : '') + ' (API level ' + api_level + ')';`

Here is the relevant [patch](https://gist.github.com/oidualc/370954b9765e6e905d08d3eaa0453c3d).

Comment: Thank you, any way to make a hook or something for this so platform add reapplies the fix?

Comment: @themis sure, basically "level" is erroneously supposed to always be defined, but this is not the case, in particular not when you are using a not yet released version of Android. This causes the whole script to crash when it tries to access level.semver (the Android version), but since this info is not mandatory for the emulator to work, the code (level ? level.semver : '') is like: "hey, is 'level' defined? If yes then get me its semver info, otherwise don't mind, let it be blank"

Comment: but I have to do it each time I add the android project

Comment: @themis Yes because this is just a workaround, the real fix is included in later versions of cordova android.

Comment: Seems to be fixed at android@~7.1.0

Comment: Here's a link that explains how to install the latest version with the fix: 
 https://cordova.apache.org/announcements/2018/02/26/cordova-android-7.1.0.html

Answer (score 9):

This is a bug in cordova-android's list_images method, it crashes when it encounters an android version on your system that's not in its list: https://github.com/apache/cordova-android/pull/422

You can apply the fix manually in `platforms/android/cordova/emulator.js` within your project

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem and what I did was to run `adb devices` on the terminal to check if my device was prorprly connected or not and I found that my device was not connected properly, I think there was a problem with my USB cable and so I disconnected the cable and connected it again an ran the same command `adb devices`, then it showed my device as connected. My problem was solved, I hope it'll help someone else.

Answer (score 0):

For me, on a Mac, the following was required to get the sdk running in the emulator:

Open Android Studio (and open your project if it doesn't open at start up)

Select 'Tools -> AVD Manager' to open the device manager tool

Right click on the relevant image (or create one if required first)

Select 'Cold Boot Now' and wait for the emulator to boot up

In a terminal cd to the folder where your `platforms` and `config.xml`. Where `cordova` commands can be run

List available devices with `adb devices` (Install it if it says not available) to get a list of running devices, and grab your EMULATOR ID. For me on this occasion it was `emulator-5554`.

Run the command `cordova run android --target "emulator-5554"` replacing `emulator-5554` with your own reference.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this error because I thought the "emulation" command would start the emulator, but it seems to only use one that is already running. Some helpful commands and checks that are available on Windows 10 once you have Android Studio and cordova installed:

1. `cordova run --list` will show no devices and give the semver error.
2. `adb devices -l` should show no devices attached.
3. Make sure your **PATH** environment variable includes `%ANDROID_SDK_ROOT%\emulator`,
   `%ANDROID_SDK_ROOT%\platform-tools`, `%ANDROID_SDK_ROOT%\tools`
4. [Emulator command line](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-commandline)

   - Run `emulator -list-avds` to see which emulators are available. If none, then add them via Android Studio.
   - `start cmd` because you'll need another command line.
   - Start an emulator - Example: `emulator -avd 7_WSVGA_Tablet_API_30` (note that underscores replace any spaces in the name)
5. `adb devices -l` should now show a device like "emulator-5554"
6. `cordova run --list` still gives a semver error. (Maybe this is a bug?)
7. `cordova run android` (from your app's project directory) should start your app using the default emulator, or you can specify which one with `cordova run android --target emulator-5554`